# Why doesnt this code compile?

Tags: c++, class, gcc, compiler-errors

I got a situation like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    void Barry() { }
};

struct Bar : private Foo
{
    template <class F> void Bleh(F Func) { Func(); }
};

struct Fooey : public Bar
{
    void Blah() { Foo f; Bar::Bleh(std::bind(&Foo::Barry, &f)); }
};
```

And it doesn't compile (g++ 4.7.3). With error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Fooey::Blah()’:
test.cpp:4:1: error: ‘struct Foo Foo::Foo’ is inaccessible
test.cpp:15:23: error: within this context
test.cpp:4:1: error: ‘struct Foo Foo::Foo’ is inaccessible
test.cpp:15:47: error: within this context
```

However, if I do this:

```
class Fooey;
void DoStuff(Fooey* pThis);

struct Fooey : public Bar
{
    void Blah() { DoStuff(this); }
};

void DoStuff(Fooey* pThis)
{
    Foo f;
    pThis->Bleh(std::bind(&Foo::Barry, &f));
}
```

It compiles just fine. What is logic behind this?

Comment: Try `&::Foo::Barry` in the first case.

Comment: @MislavBlažević Use public inheritance (or default public for struct) from Foo.

Comment: void Blah() { ::Foo f; Bar::Bleh(std::bind(&::Foo::Barry, &f)); }

Fixed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here

```
struct Fooey : public Bar
{
    void Blah() { Foo f; Bar::Bleh(std::bind(&Foo::Barry, &f)); }
};
```

name lookup for `Foo` finds the base class of `Bar` which is inaccesible because `Bar` inherits privately.

To fix it, qualify the name fully:

```
    void Blah() { ::Foo f; Bar::Bleh(std::bind(&::Foo::Barry, &f)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, inside `Foo` or any class derived from it, `Foo` is the *injected class name*; a name scoped inside `Foo`, which hides the same name for the class in the enclosing namespace. In this case, that is inaccessible due to the private inheritance.

You can work around this by explicitly referring to the name in the namespace, in this case `::Foo`. Unfortunately, that will break if you move the class into another namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's a name conflict. For each inherited type, you get a member of that name in your own class. To access the actual type, you need to refer it by its qualified name (in this case, `::Foo`).

This feature lets you use shadowed or overridden members of a base class from a derived class:

```
struct X
{
    void Foo();
};

struct Y : public X
{
    void Foo()
    {
        X::Foo(); // calls X's implementation of Foo
    }
};
```

But it does mean that if you mean `X` as in `struct X`, you need to qualify it with its full name, calling it `::X`.

Comment: This is a private vs public inheritance problem.  Nothing to do with naming conflicts.

Comment: @ZacHowland, then how come using `::Foo` instead of just `Foo` works? Besides, where are we using a privately-inherited member?

Comment: That only works because he is creating a second instance of `Foo` to bind with.  He is using a "has a" relationship, and then creating another using composition.

Comment: He's trying to call a Foo method on a _distinct_ Foo object from a class that (privately) inherits from Foo, and it doesn't work because the compiler thinks he's referring to a privately inherited member. Sounds very much like a situation where a name refers to two different things to me.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at now.

Answer (score -1):

When you inherit `Bar` from `Foo` with private inheritance, you make all of `Foo`'s member data/functions private.  So when you inherit `Fooey` from `Bar`, it cannot access any of `Foo`'s members.

For more details on private inheritance:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/access-rules-with-priv-inherit.html

```
struct Fooey : public Bar
{
    void Blah() { Foo f; Bar::Bleh(std::bind(&::Foo::Barry, &f)); }
};
```

This block, which contains the scope "fix" also creates another `Foo` (that is, Fooey already has a `Foo` object via its inheritance with `Bar` - this is creating another one and binding its `Barry`).